# Is it possible to see the names / tags of all active consumers of a queue using the RabbitMQ .NET client?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, amqp

I am creating a .NET application that will consume from several third-party queues that my application does not create or maintain, and I would like to make it so there is one consumer per queue *per instance of the process*.  When I create a consumer, I can give it a tag for the current process ID, but I don't see any way to *retrieve* that tag later, unless I hold on to the consumer object.

There are a few ways I can think of in which I can track currently open channels myself, but it would be much nicer if I could check the queue to see if there is already an active consumer on a channel that has a tag with the process ID.  `IBasicConsumer` has a `ConsumerTags` property which just returns the tags for that consumer, I don't see a way to access tags for other consumers.

I also see that `IModel` has a `ConsumerCount()` method, but that seems to return the total number of consumers on the queue, not just for a given channel.  Even then, it is the consumer count only, and no other information about them.

```cs
IModel channel = connection.CreateModel();

// Only returns the current consumer's tags
var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer();
string[] tags = consumer.ConsumerTags;

// Only returns count of total consumers
int count = channel.ConsumerCount("my.queue");

// This also returns the tag for the consumer used for the operation
string tag = channel.BasicConsume(consumer, "my.queue", true, "MyTag");
tag == "MyTag"; // true

// Hoping to do something like this
//var tags = channel.GetConsumers().SelectMany(c => c.ConsumerTags);
```

Is there a way for me to poll the queue and return the tags of any current consumers?

Comment: Exclusive queues may meet your requirements.

Comment: @LukeBakken The queues I am consuming are from a third-party, not a queue that I am creating and consuming myself, so I'm not sure that will work.  Unless I am misinterpreting the documentation on these.

Comment: I missed the part about "third party".

Comment: No worries, you didn't miss it.  Your comment prompted me to edit my question so that part was clear.  My apologies!

Answer (score 1):

Your application can get quite a bit of information via RabbitMQ's HTTP API - https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/v3.9.14/deps/rabbitmq_management/priv/www/api/index.html

I'm not 100% sure if the consumer tag is exposed, however.

Otherwise, perhaps using a queue dedicated to coordinating consumers would be a good option.